# Android: Drag and Drop issue

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm writing a SMIL composer for a class, and I was planning on making the canvas support drap and drop, so you can place pictures and text however you want. I've looked through examples and did a few on my own, but when I go to implement the drag and drop in my project, it doesn't work. Here is the main code that matters:

```
public class ComposerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.composer);

    Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    ...

    add.setOnClickListener(mClick);
    ...
}

OnClickListener mClick = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){        
        if(v.getId() == R.id.addBtn)
        {
            FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.Canvas); 
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_add, null);

            View image = (View)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);   
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon); 

            fl.addView(itemView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40));  

            image.setOnTouchListener(drag);
        }
        ...

OnTouchListener drag = new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){ 
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams par = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams(); 
        switch(v.getId()){//What is being touched 
            case R.id.image:{//Which action is being taken 
                switch(event.getAction()){ 
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{  
                        par.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight()); 
                        par.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2); 
                        v.setLayoutParams(par); 
                        break; 
                    }//inner case MOVE 
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{ 
                        par.height = 40; 
                        par.width = 40; 
                        par.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight()); 
                        par.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2); 
                        v.setLayoutParams(par); 
                        break; 
                    }//inner case UP 
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{ 
                        par.height = 60; 
                        par.width = 60; 
                        v.setLayoutParams(par); 
                        break; 
                    }//inner case UP 
                }//inner switch 
                break; 
            }//case image
        }//switch 
            return true; 
        }//onTouch 
    };//drag
}
```

Here is the composer.xml:

```
...
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/TopBar" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/addBtn" 
    android:id="@+id/Canvas"
    android:layout_gravity="top">

</FrameLayout>
...
```

and the image_add.xml:

```
<View android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

When I click the add button on my composer, it successfully adds the image to the canvas, and when I touch the image, it responds by getting bigger, from 40x40 to 60x60 like it should. But it doesn't follow my finger across the screen, and thats where I'm stuck.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I studied the Android Launcher code to see how they did drag and drop. I really like their object model. What they did, and it might be good for you to consider, is move the responsibility for handling drag and drop out to the ViewGroup in which all the draggable views are inside of. Touch events get handled there rather than in your views.

Two of the key classes:

DragLayer – implements a custom ViewGroup, which coordinates movement of views on the screen. The Launcher DragLayer is a subclass of FrameLayout.

DragController – This object is the controller that does most of the work to support dragging and dropping.

The other thing they do is not move the actual view until you drop the object you are dragging. It does not look that way though because on the screen you see a bitmap constructed from the view moving as your finger (or pointer) moves.

I built a simple example and wrote it up. See http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/
Source code of the example is there too.

Comment: I have looked at your blog, and while its good work, it just seems a little complicated. How would you go about dynamically adding ImageViews and TextViews to you DragLayer, rather than hard coding them in?

Comment: In another blog post (Part 3), I did that. If you look at the menu selection code, you will see:

// Add a new object to the DragLayer
ImageView newView = new ImageView (this);
newView.setImageResource (R.drawable.hello);
DragLayer.LayoutParams lp = new DragLayer.LayoutParams (60, 60, 80, 100);
mDragLayer.addView (newView, lp);
newView.setOnClickListener(this);
newView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

A little complicated, yes. I started with code from the Android Launcher and pared it down some. I want to study the new Dragging and Dropping at developer.android.com. And see which I like best.

Comment: Oops. Looks like comments are plain text. Sorry about that. See code posted in Part 3 on my blog.

Comment: Thanks Bill, your blog was a big help!

Comment: @Bill please help me on the question I have asked in your blogpost. Its very urgent to me.

Comment: have any idea about that if we drop image on match like two image or text match and drop it than that drop area become false means we can drag that succesfully dropped image

Comment: That's freaking brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for. @Bill Lahti you're a star!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a pre-made solution, there's this:

https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView

It's a custom ViewGroup I put together that seems like it might be suited to your project. Good luck!